# Проблема с setInterval и animation

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, асинхронность, setinterval

Необходимо, чтобы синий(С) квадратик перемещался за зеленым(З) по оси `Х`. Но если во время движения С квдарата переместить `З` квадрат, начинается ерунда с `С` квадратом. Подскажите как выйти из ситуации. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/max_shev/pen/xvOxrQ).

```js
var blue = document.getElementById('blue');
var green = document.getElementById('green');


// MOVE green
green.addEventListener("mousedown", MouseDown, false);

function MouseDown(EO) {
    EO = EO || window.event;
    green.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
    green.style.zIndex++;
    let greenPos = getElementPos(EO, green);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);

    function MouseMove(EO) {
        EO = EO || window.event;
        green.style.top = EO.clientY - greenPos.top + 'px';
        green.style.left = EO.clientX - greenPos.left + 'px';
        EO.preventDefault();
    }

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", MouseUp, false);

    function MouseUp(EO) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);
        green.style.cursor = "default";
        EO = EO || window.event;
    }
    green.addEventListener("mouseup", moveblue, false);
}

// Move blue at diagonals (quick path)

function moveblue(EO) {
    let Xposblue = (blue.getBoundingClientRect()).left;
    let Xposgreen = (green.getBoundingClientRect()).left;


    var animationX = setInterval(frameX, 0);

    // X-axis
    if (Xposblue > Xposgreen) {
        var lengthX = (Xposblue - Xposgreen) / 500;
    }
    if (Xposblue < Xposgreen) {
        var lengthX = (Xposgreen - Xposblue) / 500;
    }


    function frameX() {
        if (Xposgreen == Math.ceil(Xposblue) || Xposgreen ==  Xposblue + 100 || Xposgreen == Xposblue - 100) {
            clearInterval(animationX);
        } else if (Xposgreen > Xposblue) {
            Math.ceil(Xposblue += lengthX);
            blue.style.left = Xposblue + 'px';
        } else if (Xposgreen < Xposblue) {
            Math.ceil(Xposblue -= lengthX);
            blue.style.left = Xposblue + 'px';
        }
    };
 

}



// Position cursor over object
function getElementPos(EO, elem) {
    var posgreenUnderWindow = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        left: Math.floor(EO.clientX - posgreenUnderWindow.left),
        top: Math.floor(EO.clientY - posgreenUnderWindow.top)
    };
}
```

```css
body {
  width:100%; 
}

#green,
#blue {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#green {
    background: green;
    left: 0;
}

#blue {
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/max_shev/pen/xvOxrQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал через `setInterval`, сколько там Вы генерируете таймаутов я не смог понять, но их точно больше чем надо...

```js
var blue = document.getElementById('blue');
var green = document.getElementById('green');

setInterval(function() {
 
  let bx = blue.getBoundingClientRect().x
  let dx = bx - green.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  let adx = Math.abs(dx);

  if (adx > 1)
    blue.style.left = bx-Math.sign(dx)*Math.max(adx/44, 1) + 'px'

}, 10)


// MOVE green
green.addEventListener("mousedown", MouseDown, false);

function MouseDown(EO) {
    EO = EO || window.event;
    green.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
    green.style.zIndex++;
    let greenPos = getElementPos(EO, green);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);

    function MouseMove(EO) {
        EO = EO || window.event;
        green.style.top = EO.clientY - greenPos.top + 'px';
        green.style.left = EO.clientX - greenPos.left + 'px';
        EO.preventDefault();
    }

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", MouseUp, false);

    function MouseUp(EO) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove, false);
        green.style.cursor = "default";
        EO = EO || window.event;
    }
}

function getElementPos(EO, elem) {
    var posgreenUnderWindow = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        left: Math.floor(EO.clientX - posgreenUnderWindow.left),
        top: Math.floor(EO.clientY - posgreenUnderWindow.top)
    };
}
```

```css
#green, #blue {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#green {
    background: green;
    left: 0;
}

#blue {
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```